# hector_navigation_node problem compilation

Tags: ros, compilation, hector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I downloaded the hector_navigation package from github but doesn't succeed on using the hector_navigation_node

the error is : "ResourceNotFound: hector_exploration_node".

I downloaded the hector_gazebo and hector_slam packages too and don't have any problem to use them. Is there anything I have to add in a CMakeList.txt to compile this package?

Thank you for your answer

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195473/hector_navigation_node-problem-compilation/) by [est_CEAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20539/est_cear/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2014-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, I used only catkin_make but had to use :

```
$rosmake hector_exploration_node
```

which is from the old version of ROS.

Now it works, thank you "ingcavh". Can you modify or complete your answer so that I can validate it, or validate mine because I can't from my own?

---

Originally posted by [est_CEAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20539/est_cear/) with karma: 170 on 2014-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ingcavh](https://answers.ros.org/users/20373/ingcavh/) on 2014-11-12**:
Your welcome :D

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably, You  haven't added the hector navigation stack to your **ROS_PACKAGE_PATH**.
Verify that and if You haven't done it yet,  You could download the hector_navigation package to Catkin Workspace. Then, you have to compile the package, in catkin, using de **catkin_make** command in the catkin directory, not in the catkin source directory because You could damage the catkin workspace. If all is OK in the compilation console, You have to add the catkin workspace  to rospath using the command **source devel/setup.bash** .

After that, You could list all your packages and see your hector_navigation stack with all their packages in the rospack list.

The last step is to build  the entire package with **rosmake hector_navigation** command. If all is OK, you can launch the hector_exploration_node with the following  launch file:

```
<launch>
<node pkg="hector_exploration_node" type="exploration_planner_node" name="hector_exploration_node" output="screen">

    <rosparam file="$(find hector_exploration_node)/config/costmap.yaml" command="load" />

</node>

</launch>
```

In the costmap.yaml you can configure the footprint of your robot.

---

Originally posted by [ingcavh](https://answers.ros.org/users/20373/ingcavh/) with karma: 23 on 2014-11-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [est_CEAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20539/est_cear/) on 2014-11-12**:
Thank you for your answer.That's exactly what I did from the first time, but I still have this error :

```
ERROR:cannot launch node of type [hector_exploration_node/exploration_planner_node]:can't locate node [exploration_planner_node] in package [hector_exploration_node]
```

**Comment by [est_CEAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20539/est_cear/) on 2014-11-12**:
But I have every nodes contained in the hector_navigation pack in the rospack list, including hector_exploration_node

**Comment by [ingcavh](https://answers.ros.org/users/20373/ingcavh/) on 2014-11-12**:
DO you use the launch file in the hector_exploration_node directory? Do you compile the stack  with "osmake hector_navigation" commad? Try with these steps and write again in this post after prove that.